# cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-fdump-class-hierarchy' with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am trying to Dumping a representation of each class's hierarchy and virtual function table layout of my c++ program to a file. I managed to do it with success when I compiled it  from a command line with this option:

```
g++ -fdump-class-hierarchy main.cpp
```

My problem now is when I tried to make it with cmake I failed. The option -fdump-class-hierarchy was never used.Here is my CmakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(VTable)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
find_path(GCC_PATH g++.exe)
message("GCC_PATH = ${GCC_PATH}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${GCC_PATH}/g++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS         "-std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -fdump-class-hierarchy")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG   "-O0 -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2")
add_executable(VTable main.cpp Grandparent.cpp Parent1.cpp Parent2.cpp Child.cpp)
```

Can someone help me to get the dump file output  from the CmakeList.txt.By the way, does anyone knows any way to dump only my class code

Here is the the problem output

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.4\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" "path"
GCC_PATH = C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: path/cmake-build-debug

Problems were encountered while collecting compiler information:
    cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-fdump-class-hierarchy'

[Finished]
```

I'am using CLion IDE

Comment: Your error message isn't clear. i still can't get whether it is during configuration or build step. And you still have `-fdump-class-hierarchy` appended to linker flags.

Comment: @arrowd i forgot to delete it but it is not the problem i've tried it in the past. i removed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CLion/CMake build invokes the mingw-w64 port of GCC `g++` 8.1. The C++ compiler optiion `-fdump-class-hierarchy`
was [available in GCC 7.x](https://godbolt.org/z/1-Lh87) and earlier but
[removed in GCC 8.x](https://godbolt.org/z/5RDghz). That is why:

```
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-fdump-class-hierarchy'
```

in your CLion build. If the console commandline:

```
g++ -fdump-class-hierarchy main.cpp
```

succeeded then it invoked a different and earlier version of `g++` from a different
GCC installation - perhaps discovered earlier in your `PATH` than `C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/g++.exe`,
or perhaps discovered on a different computer (since you do not state that it was
the same one on which your CLion build fails).

Comment: Excellent exactly as you said!. The error disappeared and the compilation was made with success. One more fast last Question. May you guess why the memory dump file was not created?

Comment: @MixalisNavridis Sorry it's unclear to me what you mean. Better ask a new question.

Comment: "Since GCC version 8.0 at least these two options were replaced:
-fdump-class-hierarchy ---> -fdump-lang-class
-fdump-translation-unit ---> -fdump-lang-raw"